# Are these norms equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I have to prove thate these norms are equivalent
$$\Vert f\Vert_1^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3k\sqrt{1+\vert k\vert^2}\vert\hat{f}(k)\vert^2$$
and
$$\Vert f\Vert_2^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3k\sqrt{\lambda+\vert k\vert^2}\vert\hat{f}(k)\vert^2$$
with $\lambda>0$. I've proceeded in this way:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3k\sqrt{\lambda+\vert k\vert^2}\vert\hat{f}(k)\vert^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3k\frac{\sqrt{\lambda+\vert k\vert^2}}{\sqrt{1+\vert k\vert^2}}\vert\hat{f}(k)\vert^2\sqrt{1+\vert k\vert^2}$$
and then I've studied the function
$$f(r)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda+r^2}{1+r^2}}$$ in order to find its lower and upper bounds. What do you think about this reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea, but we change the notation, say $g(r):=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda+r^2}{1+r^2}}$. If we can show that there are positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that for each $r\geqslant 0$,
$$M_1\leqslant \sqrt{\frac{\lambda+r^2}{1+r^2}}\leqslant M_2,$$
we will be done. It's equivalent to require that $M_1$ and $M_2$ satisfy 
$$M_1^2\leqslant\frac{\lambda+r^2}{1+r^2}\leqslant M_2^2$$
for each $r>0$. Note that $g(r)^2=1+\frac{\lambda-1}{1+r^2}$, so for $\lambda\neq 1$ this is a monotone function, which has a limit at infinity.

Comment: It's just what I've done; the case $\lambda=1$ gives trivially equivalent norms.

Comment: @Mario: You have accidentally created two accounts, which is why you were not able to comment on Davide's post directly. Here is the process to merge your accounts: `From any page footer -> 'contact us' >> 'Merge user profiles'`